# How to use GroupState timeout in Spark Structured Streaming to form a time window?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to detect a continuous pattern over X minutes using Spark Structured Streaming. I wonder if I can use GroupState timeout to form a time window. 
What I want to do is, once I detect the first occurrence of a pattern in an object (EntityMetric), check if this pattern continuously occurs for all the subsequent EntityMetric objects in the stream within X minutes. After X minutes has passed, return an Alert object.

Here is the code I have but somehow I never see state.hasTimedOut() becomes true. I wonder if I missed something here? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```java
Dataset<EntityMetric> ems = spark
                    .readStream()...

KeyValueGroupedDataset<Integer, EntityMetric> groupedEm = ems.groupByKey((MapFunction<EntityMetric, Integer>) m -> m.<Integer>getEntityId(), Encoders.INT());

MapGroupsWithStateFunction<Integer, EntityMetric, Alert, Alert> continuousViolationsFunc = new MapGroupsWithStateFunction<Integer, EntityMetric, Alert, Alert>() {
            @Override
            public Alert call(Integer entityId, Iterator<EntityMetric> events, GroupState<Alert> state)
                    throws Exception {
                Alert currentAlert = null;
                Alert newAlert = null;
                …
                …
                if (state.hasTimedOut()) {
                    // How come state.hasTimedOut() is never true?
                    state.remove();
                } else if(state.exists()) {
                    currentAlert = state.get();
                    while (events.hasNext()) {
                        EntityMetric e = events.next();
                        // Pattern matching logic that instantiates and populates newAlert…
                    }
                    if(newAlert != null) {
                        state.update(newAlert);
                    }
                } else {
                    boolean startTimer = false;
                    // For the first occurrence…
                    while (events.hasNext()) {
                        EntityMetric e = events.next();
                        // Pattern matching logic that set startTimer to true…
                    }
                    if(startTimer) {
                        state.update(newAlert);
                        state.setTimeoutDuration("1 minutes");
                    }
                }
                return newAlert;
            }
};

Dataset<Alert> alerts = groupedEm.mapGroupsWithState(
                continuousViolationsFunc, 
                Encoders.bean(Alert.class), 
                Encoders.bean(Alert.class), 
                GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout());

StreamingQuery query = alerts
            .writeStream()
            .format("console")
            .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
            .start();
```

Comment: What does `groupedEm` look like? Have you defined a watermark? What's the output mode?

Comment: groupedEm is a KeyValueGroupedDataset<Integer, EntityMetric>. I did not define a watermark since I'm using ProcessingTimeTimeout. The output mode is Update.